# My URL is having static URL and wanted to test multi login, how to test using JMETER

Tags: jmeter

My URL is having static URL and wanted to test multi login, how to test using JMETER

URL example.com/xyz will not change through out the course of navigation till logout. And have lot of actions in between navigation.
This navigation is not captured through Jmeter recorder. In this situation i wanted to check multi user login say 20 users.

If any of you came across same issue and got solved, pls through some light here aswell

Comment: Let us know what you have done so far

Comment: 1. Launched the Jmeter using command line with command proxy, usrname, password, 2. Followed Jmeter step by step pdf document, 3. Set the browser proxy to localhost, 8888, 4. Set the same port number in recording controller, 5. Start recording -> Navigate through the URL pages in browser. If i have missed any thing ?

Answer (score 0):

You will be using for that:

- CSV Data Set that will contain your logins. Make it expose variable **login** for example
- Then in Http Request replace that parameter value for login by ${login}

Read for reference:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config
- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, Firstly my statics URL's are not being captured in recording controller. how to deal with it ?

Comment: Search stackoverflow , there are a lot of answer on this issue

Comment: Hi UBIK.. i looked into stack over flow.. its not matching with my scenerio. can you pls point out with any information.. thanks